# k-tuples from [n] with no consecutive elements

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

for first k-1 elements their next elements may or may not be a consecutive element. and there C(n,k) ways of selecting k elements for n elements. But out of 2^(k-1) ways, one way is such that no element has its consecutive element.

Hence the number of ways would be C(n,k) - 2^(k-1) + 1

But that would not work for k > n/2. So how to continue?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  What you wrote is not clear.  What's the difference between "next element" and "consecutive element"

Comment: Note that, for $(n,k)=(5,2)$ the answer is $6$, as the good selections are $13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 35$ but your formula appears to give $\binom 52-2^1+1=10-2+1=9$.

Comment: @lulu Aren't $k$-tuples (as opposed to subsets) ordered?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Well, yes...but the OP specifically said that there were $\binom nk$ unrestricted choices, so I assumed they meant unordered.  And, if "ordered" was intended, there are $12$ options for $(n,k)=(5,2)$, which still doesn't match the formula.